access denied when running debug in visual studio 2022 as admin
My work env

windows 10
Visual Studio 2022

I am developing a win32 program and when I run debug, it runs fine when I open vs2022 normally, that is to say not opening vs2022 as admin.
But when I run vs2022 as admin and run debug, the first thing that pops up is an error msgbox saying
uable to start program ~.exe
Access Denied
any help or hints to fix this are welcome
thanks

It looks like your issue may be related to permission settings. First, check the permissions of the folder. Make sure the folder containing your project and executable file has the appropriate permissions set for both standard user and administrator accounts. Right-click the folder, select "Properties," then click the "Security" tab to confirm that both types of accounts have the necessary permissions.
